# Open Id Connect Network Activation

Tags: single-sign-on, platform-bug, open-id-connect

I have configured a salesforce instance to use Google for user Authentication via Open Id Connect. This is for users with full Salesforce licenses to login to Salesforce.

When I log in from a new network location (un-activated IP address) via the Google authentication, after successfully completing the google login I am routed to a page (at /_nc_external/identity/ic/ICNotNeeded) with the following content:

"Activation complete
Your device has been automatically activated based upon network location.
-- Continue -- (Button)."

On clicking Continue, my browser is redirected to the salesforce home page (/home/home.jsp), and then back to the login page, I assume because I am not logged in properly. Despite this, my IP address is added to the Activations list (Setup -> Security Controls -> Activations), and I can subsequently log in using the same Open Id Connect mechanism without a problem until I move to a new location.

I believe this is incorrect behaviour. The message on the page suggests to me that I have logged in successfully and clicking Continue will take me to the home page. But salesforce support deny there is any issue. (And then closed my case claiming that I was requesting developer support). They have pointed me towards some articles on white listing IP addresses.

My understanding is that I should not need to pass through activation for my login unless I am logging in from a new browser at a new IP address.

Has anyone successfully configured Salesforce with Open Id Connect to avoid this issue?

Comment: FYI, this has also happened to me when using two-factor authentication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was reported to Salesforce as a defect and was eventually accepted by support as an issue. It should be resolved in "Spring 14 or a later major release".

For anyone using OpenID Connect, it might also be useful to be aware that Internal Server Errors are currently experienced by a user when logging in using OpenID Connect from an un-activated browser or network location, and entering the activation code sent to them by Email or SMS. A subsequent login attempt is successful. Again the issue has been logged with Salesforce.

Comment: Thanks James, do you have a reference to the salesforce.com defect?

Comment: @DuffJ No, I'm afraid not. Support would not post this on Known Issues, I think the "activated automatically" message has been classified as a feature. It looks to me like this has not been resolved in Spring 14 either sadly, I last checked in a sandbox a week or two ago and the issue was still present. I also poked the PM on twitter but no news https://twitter.com/jamesmelv/status/446209146611056640. Your other comment makes sense, I can imagine that 2 factor auth might be tied into the same framework, did you log a ticket?

Comment: I raised a support case number __10418791__ "Unable to log in to sandbox with two-factor authentication" - will let you know what they say. I've referenced this URL in the support case too.

Comment: Sorry,  for clarity, the issue in this question was logged under 10003040. The email activation ISE/GACK was 10046588 and the SMS one was 10020939.

Comment: salesforce support has closed off my issue as "awaiting bug fix". The bug fix reference is __W-2009113__ if anyone needs it. Expected delivery date is "summer 2014".

Comment: This was resolved in the Summer 14 release

Answer (score 0):

I recently encountered this again and was able to circumvent it by using the SalesforceA app to log in and temporarily removing my 2-Factor authentication. Once I had done that I could log in from my desktop browser to restore the required security settings. This works by logging in from a different network, so your cellphone must either be on a different network or using Cellular service. Presumably you could also log in from your desktop if you used a different network.